# Handlebars Helper returning array but rendering comma delimited string

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have an array of objects that I am trying to display in categories using bootstrap panels. To get all of the different categories in the array I created a helper that loops through the array and returns an array of strings which contains all the different distinct categories.

Here are my two helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("GetFamilies", function (array) {
    var families = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var item = array[i];

        if (families.indexOf(item.Family) <= -1) {
            families.push(item.Family);
        }
    }
    console.log("====================Families");
    console.log(families);
    return families;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("GetFamiliyPieces", function (array, familyName) {
    var result = _.filter(array, function (obj) {
        // return true for every valid entry!
        return obj.Family == familyName;
    });

    console.log("====================Family Pieces");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});
```

Here is the html:

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="toolbox-accordion">
        {{#GetFamilies pieces}}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#toolbox-accordion" href="#{{this}}">
                        {{this}}
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="{{this}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{#GetFamilyPieces pieces this}}

                    <div class="toolbox_item" data-type="{{TypeName}}" data-type-id="{{TypeID}}" title="{{TypeDescription}}" data-input-count="{{Length Inputs}}" data-output-count="{{Length Outputs}}">
                        <span id="line"></span>
                        <div class='typename'>{{ShortName TypeName}}</div>
                    </div>

                    {{/GetFamilyPieces}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/GetFamilies}}
    </div>
```

In the Console I am hitting the GetFamilies Helper:

[image]

But not hitting the GetFamilyPieces helper.

My rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="toolbox-container">

    <div class="panel-group" id="toolbox-accordion">
Circuit,Component,Conductor    </div>


</div>
```

As you can see it is just rendering a comma delimited string of what the array contains. Do you know why the full html is not being rendered?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the comma-delimited string because that is the result when an array in JavaScript is .toStringed.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString):

> For Array objects, the toString method joins the array and returns one
>   string containing each array element separated by commas.

This means that `["Circuit", "Component", "Conductor"].toString()` results in `"Circuit,Component,Conductor"`.

The reason why the rest of your template is not rendered after calling your helper is because your helper is not written properly. Your [Block Helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) should return a string containing the HTML that is to be rendered. Because your helper returns an array, the `toString()` of that array is rendered. In order to access the inner template of a Block Helper, Handlebars provides a function, `options.fn`, to which you pass context data object. Your helpers must pass each item in the array argument to the `options.fn` function and join the results. A working implementation would look something like the following:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("GetFamilies", function (array, options) {
    return array
        .reduce((memo, el) => {
            if (memo.indexOf(el.Family) === -1) {
                memo.push(el.Family);
            }
            return memo;
        }, [])
        .reduce((memo, family) => memo += options.fn(family), '');
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("GetFamilyPieces", function (array, familyName, options) {
    return array
        .filter(el => el.Family === familyName)
        .reduce((memo, el) => memo += options.fn(el), '');
});
```

Please note that within your `#GetFamilies` Block Helper, `pieces` does not necessarily exist within your context data. You must tell Handlebars that to step up a context frame to find `pieces` with a path: `../pieces`.

An alternative solution, and, judging by your helpers, the one it looks like you were aiming for, would be to use a standard (non-Block) [Handlebars Helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers). This would allow you to return the arrays from your helpers as you were doing, and then pass the resulting array to the existing `#each` Block Helper. Your template would need to be changed to the following:

```
{{#each (GetFamilies pieces)}}
    {{#each (GetFamilyPieces ../pieces this)}}

    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```